# @+id missing in TextView of android studio and that place showing abstract, class, enum, final

Tags: javascript, java, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, shortcode

[ In Textview of android studio, after android:id="" (the hidden of @+id missing and showing abstract, class, enum, final, import, interface, package, public). So that i can't make showing score.  ][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJtzw.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJtzw.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwBt1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused on how to add an id, here's the basic code

`android:id="@+id/nameofid"`

Comment: But, I found abstract, class, enum... instead of @+id. @+id is missing.